# How reload page with same url

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9

I need to reload page at the same url in angular. So i read this solution and it works:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefreshComponent', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['Your actualComponent']);
});
```

My question is:this is solution is a bad solution?
First needs to load a url and after redirect to another url? Anyone can says me if this is a bad solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't touch `AppRoutingModule`, don't think it is a good idea. I would prefer to affect as few code as possible. For this reason I have 3 methods:

```
  private saveDefaultRouteSettings() {
    this.defaultRouteReuseStrategy = this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute;
    this.defaultOnSameUrlNavigation = this.router.onSameUrlNavigation;
  }

  private setReloadRouteSettings() {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
  }

  private restoreDefaultRouteSettings() {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = this.defaultRouteReuseStrategy;
    this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = this.defaultOnSameUrlNavigation;
  }
```

And use them like this:

Component constructor:

```
this.saveDefaultRouteSettings();
```

Redirect to the same page itself:

```
this.setReloadRouteSettings();
this.router.navigate(
  [`my_page_url`],
  {
    relativeTo: null,
    replaceUrl: true,
    skipLocationChange: true,
    state: this.currentRouteState
  }
).then(ready => {
  if (ready) {
    this.restoreDefaultRouteSettings();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reload current page like this:

```
 location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

import like this in your `AppRoutingModule` where you imported your routes:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to navigate to another url first.

Below code will work for you:

```js
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
    return false;
};
```

Comment: yash the  problem is that I have  a menu with two menu item A and B. I have just try your solution and When I reload for the first time the page it work but when I go to another B and after I come back to A , the componenet with url B is not laded but it is load the component A

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156857/how-to-reload-the-url-in-the-same-page